# User memory limit exceeded in gee , How to resolve this error?

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine, outofrangeexception

I'm fairly new to GEE, and I'm trying to process some imagery, then download the results. I need to classify Sentinel data to isolate different land cover types, remove clouds, and calculate vegetation indices. Then, I need to export these data to do further analyses in R. I've managed to do all of the masking and calculating vegetation indices, LULC, but when I go to export the data, it gives me the user memory limit exceeded error. I tried to only download 1 year of data at a time but got the same error. I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm doing, which is to do the heavy processing of the data in GEE then export it to do the additional analyses elsewhere. Any recommendations?

LINK OF MY CODE : https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5f1f347f57bc44985428254b67286fb

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code here, as formatted text, as a [mcve]. Links can break, making the question useless for others with similar problems. Make sure you only ask one question at a time, as in the [tour]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading to Google drive. It allows you to save larger files from gee

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting